# inverse search and shadows tikzlibrary

Tags: tikz-pgf, texworks, forward-inverse-search

The `shadows` tikzlibrary makes the inverse search in TeXworks fail in the **first** page. I included a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\lipsum

\end{document}
```

In the first page, I am redirected to `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex`, instead of my LaTeX source file. From the second page, it works as intended. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Does it go to `pgflibrarycalc.code.tex` if you change `shadows` to `calc`?

Comment: @percusse No it doesn't.